# How do xaml elements inherit properties like FontFamily and Foreground?

Tags: xaml, properties

I discovered today that when I style something in XAML, if I leave the FontFamily out, it will inherit it from the closest ancestor that has a FontFamily. How is it figuring out which element to reference?

```
<Page 
    ...
    Foreground="Green">
    <ContentControl Foreground="Purple">

        <TextBlock Text="I am purple unless ContentControl Foreground is not set."/>

    </ContentControl>
</Page>
```

My First thought was that it was using the DataContext somehow, but if the reference object isn't the data context, it still inherits these properties.

I tried googling it, and got a lot of links showing me how to **set** the Background in a style, but I want to understand how it works when **unset**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out which UI framework you are using, UWP or WPF. So I write them both.

- For WPF, you can read [Property Value Inheritance | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance).
- For UWP, you can read [Dependency properties overview - UWP app developer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview).

For both WPF and UWP, this kind of property is `DependencyProperty`. The property value you keep unset is **from multiple sources**.

- WPF

  - Property system coercion.
  - Active animations, or animations with a Hold behavior.
  - **Local value**. *The value you set in your XAML code*.
  - TemplatedParent template properties.
  - Implicit style.
  - Style triggers.
  - Template triggers.
  - Style setters.
  - Default (theme) style.
  - **Inheritance**. *The value you just find out from the ancestors*.
  - Default value from dependency property metadata.
- UWP is much simpler

  - Animated values.
  - Local value.
  - Templated properties.
  - Style setters.
  - Default value.

You write your own dependency property of WPF as an inherited property, but you cannot do the same in UWP.